# Does an HTML select lose document flow when placed inside a CSS drop menu?

Tags: html, css, forms, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

Okay, that question definitely will create confusion, but it's the only way I can think to ask it.

Here's the gist of what's occurring. I have this menu:
EDIT: here's the requested fiddle (NOTE: you have to view this in IE8 in order to replicate the issue) [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X57Hb/)

```
<ul>
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">Sort</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>link 1</li>
        <li>link 2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">Filter</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <div class="usedproducts-filter-container"> 
                <select>
                    <option>option 1</option>
                    <option>option 2</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I'm using this CSS to style it and create the drop down functionality:

```
ul {
    position: relative;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
}

ul > li {
    display: inline;
}

ul > li > a {
    color: #666666;
    margin-left: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
}

ul > li:hover > a {
    color: #111111;
}

ul > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
    display: none;
}

ul > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

ul > li > ul > li {
    display: block;
}
```

When I hover over the sort menu, it displays, and I'm able to click a link.
However, when I hover over the filter menu, it displays the drop down, I can move my mouse around within the drop down fine, but when I click the select box to open it and I move my mouse inside to select and option, the whole drop down menu disappears. It's as if the select box isn't actually contained within the UL drop down.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this without using JS? Also, I think it is important to state that this is in IE8. I have no idea how it's functioning in other browsers because this is being designed for supporting IE8 only.(Don't ask, it's a long story).

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem in jsfiddle or something, or provide us a link where we can see the specific behaviour.

Comment: I edited and added the http://jsfiddle.net/X57Hb/ however, it needs to be viewed in IE8 to replicate the same environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is indeed because the drop-down part of the `<select>` is outside of the document (it is a UI element).

If you can, consider using `<select size="N">`, with `N` being a suitable number. This will change your drop-down to a more "option list"-type element, but it will be compatible with `:hover`.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Setting a size won't suit me, so I'll have to interfere with some JS. Not a big deal but I was hoping to do it with pure CSS. Thanks again, mate :)